How to convert `VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate` to Swift 6 Concurrency
So I have this code:
fileprivate class DocumentScanDelegate: NSObject, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
  
  static let shared = DocumentScanDelegate()

  var compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1
  var onScanSuccess: (UIImage) -> Void = { _ in }
  
  func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
    
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    
    guard scan.pageCount >= 1 else { return }
    let lastPage = scan.imageOfPage(at: scan.pageCount - 1)
    let compressed = lastPage.compressed(quality: compressionQuality)
    onScanSuccess(compressed)
  }
  
  func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
  }
  
  func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
  }
  

}


I got 2 errors:

shared:


Static property 'shared' is not concurrency-safe because non-'Sendable' type 'DocumentScanDelegate' may have shared mutable state; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode


the 3 controller.dismiss calls:


Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'dismiss(animated:completion:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Both makes sense. So what I did is adding @MainActor to DocumentScanDelegate . Then first warning disappeared. But the second warning becomes:

Main actor-isolated instance method 'documentCameraViewController(_:didFinishWith:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Then I use @preconcurrency to annotate VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate conformance:
@MainActor
fileprivate class DocumentScanDelegate: NSObject, @preconcurrency VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
  ...
}

This @preconcurrency trick is very similar to WWDC 2024's video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2024/10169/?time=1520)
The error becomes:

Main actor-isolated instance method 'documentCameraViewController(_:didFinishWith:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

With the following sub-error:

Class 'VNDocumentCameraScan' does not conform to the 'Sendable' protocol

Then I use @preconcurrency import:
@preconcurrency import VisionKit

The same warning persists.
There's also a new warning (why?):

'@preconcurrency' attribute on module 'VisionKit' has no effect


Why do you need shared? Why not just create a DocumentScanDelegate only when you need it?

Because i want to launch doc scan from a static helper function, and need a way to keep this delegate around

The "@preconcurrency has no effect" warning reminds me of this issue. Are you importing anything else that might also import VisionKit? If VisionKit is "covered" by another non-preconcurrency import, @preconcurrency import VisionKit will have no effect.

I have a @preconcurrency import Vision in another file of this module. Though I believe VisionKit relies on Vision, not the other way around.

I just tried removing @preconcurrency for Vision, and add @preconcurrency for VisionKit. Then I got the 2 warnings: (1) for Vision: Add '@preconcurrency' to suppress 'Sendable'-related warnings from module 'Vision', and (2) for VisionKit: '@preconcurrency' attribute on module 'VisionKit' has no effect.

Remove all the imports of VisionKit in the file. Does the file still compile? If it does, that means something else is importing VisionKit, and figure out what that is.

No it doesn't compile. I also searched the whole codebase, and these are the only 2 files that imports vision related frameworks (one imports Vision and the other imports VisionKit). Just to be extra safe, I also deleted the file that imports Vision, and still the same warning.


"Then I use @preconcurrency to annotate VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate conformance:"

Why not just wrap your calls to controller in a task instead of adding @MainActor to your whole class? Task { @MainActor in controller.dismiss(animated: true) }
The VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate protocol's functions are not guaranteed to be called on @MainActor, if the annotation is missing in the protocol definition (also I can find nothing about it being called on the main thread in the documentation).

@fabianm you can't pass UIViewController across the isolation boundary since it's not Sendable (unless i am missing something?. could you write an answer? thanks)

Following up on our conversation in the comments here.
Considering your last question, I'm not exactly sure why this works tbh, but I tried it with strict concurrency checking set to "complete" and it does not complain. My best guess is, that it's not an issue to capture controller in the Task closure, because it's guaranteed to be accessed only on the @MainActor there.
import VisionKit

private class DocumentScanDelegate: NSObject, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
    @MainActor
    static let shared = DocumentScanDelegate()

    var compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1
    var onScanSuccess: (UIImage) -> Void = { _ in }

    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
        Task { @MainActor in 
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        guard scan.pageCount >= 1 else { return }
        let lastPage = scan.imageOfPage(at: scan.pageCount - 1)
        let compressed = lastPage.compressed(quality: compressionQuality)
        onScanSuccess(compressed)
    }

    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}


have you enabled complete checking in build settings?

Yes, it is set to complete. I also tried to use Swift 6 and that doesn't complain as well.

Weird, I don't see the warning here. I do see @MainActor annotation in apple's definition of VNDocumentCameraViewController - does it implicitly mean it is also Sendable?

Ah, "Classes marked with @MainActor are implicitly sendable, because the main actor coordinates all access to its state. These classes can have stored properties that are mutable and nonsendable." From apple's doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sendable#

I am accepting this answer, but I highly suspect that in the future VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate protocol itself will be marked as MainActor (since it's UI related operations), by then we won't need this Task operation. But we will see.

Thanks. You're probably right about that. If you're absolutely certain, that it'll always be called on the main thread, you could also use MainActor.assumeIsolated to avoid scheduling the view controller dismissal async.

I am 99% certain. However, it is not documented anywhere, so i'd play safe here for now and use the Task { @MainActor in }
